# Do .Net 4 Framework WinForms Applications Need Previous Versions?

Tags: .net-4.0, setup-deployment, prerequisites

.NET 4 has a new CLR.

If I install the V4 framework on a PC will it install if there are NO earlier framework versions on that PC? Also, will my WinForms applications, targeted at .NET 4 run smoothly with no other framework installed?

Comment: As @nick mentioned this Windows Imaging Component was a real snag! For anyone else coming around here, It needs to be installed on **WinXPx64** and **Windows Server 2003** (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your app will run smoothly. .net 4 is not dependent on previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4 is dependent on something called Windows Imaging Component and Windows installer 3.1

Comment: yes but both those components are NOT part of previous versions of .net correct?

Comment: I know the 3.1 installer is not and I'm pretty sure that the imaging component was not